# recommend me some texts on the history of the non-western mathematics

Tags: reference-request, math-history

I would like to self study the detailed history of the non-western mathematics. I have started the literature of Barton (7th Ed.) but it primarily concentrated on Western and American Mathematics. Would someone recommend me some texts belonging to the domain?

Comment: The M.A.A. has a few, I think, http://www.maa.org/publications/books  Hmmmm  maybe AMS: http://www.ams.org/bookstore

Comment: The Mathematics of Egypt, Mesopotamia, China, India, and Islam: A Sourcebook. Victor J. Katz, Annette Imhausen

Comment: bunch of references at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_mathematics

Comment: The collection edited by Katz is useful. For Islamic mathematics, Berggren and Berggren and Lennart. For China, despite flaws, the book by Matzloff. Negative recommendation: The Crest of the Peacock.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Can you elaborate on your negative recommendation? The [reviews at amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0691135266) seem pretty positive. I have the book, but I haven't looked at it much (thus, I have no real opinion on it) because my historical interests are mainly in the last 150 years or so.

Comment: It has been quite a while since I went through it carefully, looking to "mine" it for the history of math course I have taught a bunch of times. Too many dubious or highly stretched precedence claims. Too many poor descriptions of work in Islamic mathematics where I had read the (translated) original. Nice book from a "political" point of view, as a corrective.

Comment: There's also Kim Plofker's "Mathematics in India".